# Comment out the current line

Tags: emacs

How do I comment out the line at point without marking the region?

Comment: Is your answer here? --> http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comment-Commands.html

Comment: I did see that but I want to comment out the current line without having to mark it.

Comment: Can you create a macro that will just insert the appropriate comment characters at the appropriate place in the line (right before the first non-whitespace character) that you happen to be on

Comment: I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: Creating keyboard macros: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros.  You should create one that marks the current line, converts it to a comment, and then unmarks it.

Comment: Finally this worked `(fset 'comment-line
      "\C-a\C-@\C-e\M-xcomment-or-uncomment-region\C-m\C-a")`

Comment: Also check out [whole-line-or-region.el](http://www.northbound-train.com/emacs/whole-line-or-region.el), which has notes on integrating with the handy comment/uncomment function `comment-dwim`. (The entire library is handy if you want operations like copy or cut to act on the entire line when no region is active.) Hope that helps.